# pointers in c- " is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?"

Tags: c, pointers

Im trying to assign new value to afield in a nested structures using pointer,
but I keep getting the compile error in the title,
here is my code:

```
    struct Territory{
int x1;
int x2;
int y1;
int y2;
};

struct Country{
   char *name;
   pCity *cities;
   int numCities;
   pTerritory *countryTerr;

};
typedef struct Territory* pTerritory;
typedef struct Country* pCountry;`struct Territory 
ter_for_country;
struct Country new_country;
pCountry country_pointer;
country_pointer = &new_country;

ter_for_country.x1 = 3;
ter_for_country.x2 = 3;
ter_for_country.y1 = 3;
ter_for_country.y2 = 3;

new_country.numCities=2;
new_country.countryTerr = &ter_for_country;
```

now suppose I want to change "x1" of new_country using the pointer "country_pointer", how would I do that?
I tried :

```
country_pointer->countryTerr->x1 = 25;
```

but I get errors, can you help?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I think you should try again creating a minimal and complete example of your code, since now the reader has to try to read your code. It seems that also some code has been cut off, I guess...

Comment: Another good example why typedef'ing pointers isn't a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have one level of pointers too many: `pTerritory` is defined to be a pointer to `struct Territory`, and in `struct Country` you make `countryTerr` a pointer to `pTerritory`.  This gives you a pointer to a pointer, where you want a pointer to a struct.  Solution: change `countryTerr` to be of type `pTerritory` (instead of `pTerritory *`).

Answer (score 0):

Member `pTerritory *countryTerr` is actually of type `struct Territory **` (note that `pTerritory` is already a pointer type, and you add an additional `*` then with `*countryTerr`.

Write

```
struct Country{
   char *name;
   pCity *cities;
   int numCities;
   pTerritory countryTerr;
};
```

and your statement `country_pointer->countryTerr->x1 = 25` should compile (and work) as intended.

Anyway, to avoid such pitfalls due to such "explicit pointer types", the `*`-notation together with plain types it is commonly understood and - in my opinion - more straight and easier to read:

```
typedef struct Territory{
 int x1;
 int x2;
 int y1;
 int y2;
} Territory;

typedef struct Country{
   char *name;
   pCity *cities;
   int numCities;
   Territory *countryTerr;
} Country;
```